# Possible outcomes

Tags: combinatorics

There are 2 Champions league soccer matches today. PSG vs Man Utd & FC Porto Vs Roma.

Each game can end in a Win, Draw, or Loss. What is the total number of outcomes of todays matches?

Ex: Man Utd Wins vs PSG and FC Porto draw against Roma which is one outcome.

How or what is the formula to calculate that?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a tree diagram?

Answer (score 0):

There are two events that are independent with each other:
Two events:

1. Man Utd vs. PSG
2. Roma vs. Porto

Independence:
The result of the first game has nothing to do with the second game, and vice versa.

For the first game, there are three outcomes:
Win, Draw, Lose
and so is the second game.

Therefore, the total outcomes of the two games together is

The outcome of the first game X the outcome of the second game:
3 X 3 = 9
The multiplication suggests the two games are independent with each other

Specifically: (outcome. first-game second-game)

1. 3 3
2. 1 3
3. 0 3
4. 3 1
5. 1 1
6. 0 1
7. 3 0
8. 1 0
9. 0 0

First colomn
3. Man Utd wins
1. Man Utd draws
0. Man Utd loses

Second colomn
3. Roma wins
1. Roma Utd draws
0. Roma Utd loses

So to conclude, there are totally 9 outcomes for these two games together.